# linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-52-generic for jammy 22.04 does not found archive

Tags: package-management, kernel, dpkg

I use Ubuntu 22.04 jammy version and The Error that linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-52-generic package needs to be reinstalled, but the required archive file cannot be found. I can not install `sudo apt install net-tools` or anything.

I searched to the package but I can not found anywhere. A website [UbuntuUpdates.org](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/jammy/main/security/linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-52-generic)
shows as delete package.

I selected old version kernel image that 5.15.0.47-generic for computer boot from advanced boot options and I set to the version of GRUB_DEFAULT.

And the error still show.

How can I fix it?